# Highlight a particular value in X axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to highlight particular values on x axis in Matplotlib .

```
list1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] - xaxis values 
list2=[1,2,23,4,5,6,7,8,9] - y-axis values 
list3=[2,3,6,7]

plt.plot(list1,list2)
plt.show()
```

I want to highlight the xaxis labels as well its corresponding values in any color like red/green or whatever only when list3 value is present in list1

Comment: Are you looking to change the color of `xticklabel` and the `marker` for the data mentioned in `list3` to red/green color?

Comment: Yes .. list1 is X-axis and list2 is Y -axis                                                                 First I want to check if the elements of list3 are present in list1 or Not .                      If yes , then change the color of only those values of X axis (list1) where list3 elements are present .                                                                            Highlighting those values or labels on x-axis is enough for me

Comment: Change color of what? xticklabel and marker?

Comment: Currently I am not aware how to highlight what values of list3 which are present in list1 on the X-axis . Once I am able to highlight those values then I just want to highlight both xticklable and the corresponding x-axis value in some color (eg: green/red)

Answer (score 1):

One option, independently of the axis labels, could be to plot markers for the target values:

```
import numpy as np

m = np.isin(list1, list3)

plt.plot(list1, list2)
plt.plot(np.array(list1)[m], np.array(list2)[m], ls='', marker='x')
```

Output:

[image]

If you also want the labels:

```
m = np.isin(list1, list3)

ax = plt.subplot()
ax.plot(list1, list2)
ax.plot(np.array(list1)[m], np.array(list2)[m], ls='', marker='x')

S = set(list3)
for tick in ax.get_xticklabels():
    if int(tick.get_text()) in S:
        tick.set_color('r')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks it worked for me .. I needed one more help .Whenever the list3 value is present in list1 ::                                                                                                   1 .Change the color of the value which you already gave a solution                          2 . Don't change the color of the value but just change the background to some color ..eg (red/green) whenever list3 element is present in list1

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `matplotlib.pyplot.annotate` or `axvspan`. These are 3 possible solution I could think of.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
list1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] #- xaxis values 
list2=[1,2,23,4,5,6,7,8,9] #- y-axis values 
list3=[2,3,6,7]

plt.plot(list1,list2)

for value in list3:
    index = list1.index(value)
    x = list1[index]
    y = list2[index]
    plt.annotate("X",(x,y),xytext=(x-.1,y-.25), color="red")
    plt.annotate("X",(x,y),xytext=(x-.1,-0.5), color="red")
    plt.axvspan(list1[index]-.1, list1[index]+.1, alpha=0.3, color="green")
plt.show()
```

In this case in the `xytext` I substracted `0.1` and `0.25` (or `-0.5`) just for better overlapping of the "X" since this method is used for text annotation. In the case of `axvspan` I used `+/-0.1` of the coloring range.

Hope it helps!